# Is it safe/wise to run Drupal alongside bespoke business web apps in production?

Tags: windows, sql-server, iis, drupal

I'm interested to know the general community feeling about the safety of running Drupal alongside bespoke, business critial ASP.NET MVC apps on a production server.

Previously my employer's Drupal based 'visitor website' was hosted as a managed service with a 3rd party. While the LoB sites were hosted in-house. That 3rd party is no longer available so I'm considering my options:
Bring Drupal in-house
Find another 3rd party

My concern is that I have little experience with Drupal administration (and no experience securing it) and that the addition of PHP to my IIS server poses a security risk.

Is there a best practice that I can follow in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice in this situation when working on a mission critical system would be to:

Learn all about what you need to know to host it, dry run the migration, test it , migrate it, test it again, administer it and update it. Or simply outsource it.

Outsourcing doesn't have to mean a fully managed service it could simply mean an account with a 'stack it high sell it cheap' web host.

It probably is safe but PHP isn't a technology you already support internally I wouldn't rush to add it to your skill set for one website that you have suggested is somewhat unimportant.

Comment: Thanks. I'm inclined to agree with you. The site is important from a marketing perspective but it's not doing any actual work. I think the main factor is not wanting to support another technology. Outsourcing looks like the way forward.